# Determine whether Window scaling is enabled in linux

Tags: linux

I want to know whether we have any **command** which tells whether the **windows scaling option** is **enabled** in the **Linux machine**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sysctl` to both read and write the setting. Reading:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling
```

Writing:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=1
```

For writing you have to be root (or use sudo).